# Is `git diff` related to `diff`?

Tags: git, diff

Is `git diff` related to `diff`?

1. Is `git diff` implemented based on `diff`?
2. Is [the command line syntax of `git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) similar to [that of `diff`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html)? Does learning one help  using the other much?
3. are their output files following the same format? Can they be both used by `git patch` and `patch`? (Is there `git patch`? How is it related to `patch`?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

The file format is interoperable.  Git uses the best format, `diff -u`.  It also extends it to represent additional types of changes.

The equivalent to `patch` is `git apply`.  It stages the changes in the index as well as applying them to the working tree.

I remember `git apply` being stricter than `patch`, although the reference documentation doesn't seem to make an explicit comparison.  It does mention several tests / errors which can be enabled or disabled.

The reference documentation also suggests that it could be used as "a replacement for GNU patch" - even outside of a git repository, if you use a certain option.

Comment: One interesting question from the OP remains unanswered: "Is git diff implemented based on diff". Do you know about this @sourcejedi?

Comment: @clapas I don't know.

Comment: I really don't think the patches are interoperable. git will prefix the source and dest files with a and b. Also git can make binary patches which diff doesn't understand.

Answer (score 5):

git-diff offers more features than diff and I don't think the output patches are interoperable (without some additional options), since diff will produce lines like

```
diff -ruNa dir1/file1.txt dir2/file1.txt
```

while git-diff produces lines like

```
diff --git a/dir1/file1.txt b/dir2/file1.txt
```

(notice the source and dest prefix, toggleable with `--no-prefix`, and different options)

Here are some additional features of git-diff:

- Can record moved/renamed files, while [diff can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141735/when-diffing-folders-how-can-i-detect-moved-or-renamed-files)
- Uses recursive mode, unified diffs, and handles new/deleted files by default (`diff -ruN`)
- Supports different algorithms for finding differences
- Supports git binary patches which encodes binary data as ASCII